# Charset inside Javascript from dynamic page in Delphi

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, utf-8, delphi-xe

I'm generating dynamic HTML inside Delphi. I have no problem displaying UTF-8 strings inside the webpage body. I use HTMLEscape to encode regular strings (all the strings inside the string list are previously escaped).

The problem occurs inside the scripts (javascript) functions inside the dynamic page.

```
'<script language="javascript" charset="UTF-8">'+#10+
(...)
'function ProcessAddUserButton(){'+#10+
'alert("'+web_content_sl[70]+'");'+
'}'+#10+
```

For a string with the word "usuário" I get `usu&#225;rio` in the alert box, but if I use the same string inside the HTML body it will display correctly. I've tried to include the charset inside the script definition as you can see above, but with no success. I don't understand why I'm getting different results from the same string in the same page.

The META tag from the dynamic page is:

```
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+#10+
```

As anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is literally `"usu&#225;rio"`. It will only show up "correctly" in a context that decodes html. You can also manually decode it with javascript but it's easier just to pass the literal character from server in the first place instead of html encoding it.

Here's function to manually decode it in javascript:

```
function decodeHTML( str ) {
    return str.replace( /(?:&#x([a-fA-F0-9]+);|&#([0-9]+);)/g, function(full, m1, m2 ) {
        if( m1 ) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(m1, 16));
        }
        else {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(m2, 10));
        }
    });
}

alert(decodeHTML( "usu&#225;rio" )) //alerts "usuário"
```

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, I should disable the string encoding (HTMLescape). I've already done that and the result is "usu�rio" instead of "usu& #225 ;rio".

Comment: @MiguelE Yeah, that's because the string is not encoded in UTF-8. If this is in some file, that file is not saved in UTF-8 encoding. If this is from database, the database is not using UTF-8 and so on. It is not enough that your website claims to be in UTF-8 encoding, it also needs to send out UTF-8 encoded content.

Comment: The string origin is not from file or db it's generated from: "web_content_sl.Add(HTMLEscape('Complete todos os dados do novo usuário.'));//70" so it should be UTF8 by default in Delphi XE (the structure is a TStringlist). No file or db in the cycle.

Comment: @MiguelE Where is that code if not in a file?. You need to save that file in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: The code (the whole HTML page) is generated in runtime into a string. I have a HTTP Server inside my application. There is no file.

Comment: Where did you write `'Complete todos os dados do novo usuário.'` if not in a file?

Comment: I'm streaming the runtime generated string to the browser who has made the HTTP request.

Comment: @MiguelE Where do you tell the runtime to generate this string?

Comment: Inside a procedure triggered by the HTTP request made by the browser accessing the IP served by my application. Anyway, that's not the point here, if I use the same string inside the HTML body of the page I get correct results. The problem just happens when the string is called by the javascript alert.

Comment: @MiguelE How did the runtime come up with the procedure? Did you write up some code? Did you save that code in a file somewhere? Was that file, containing the code (and thus the string), saved in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I've edited my above comment. The issue is just the alert inside the javascript. The same string works perfectly inside the HTML body.

Comment: @MiguelE yes that's what I initally explained in my answer. The string is html encoded, and thus needs to be html decoded to show correctly. On a html page, html encoded strings show correctly automatically because well... it's a html page. The string is `"usu&#225;rio"` and javascript is technically the one that shows it correctly because that's what the string is. I am not familiar with delphi but you need to research how to make delphi output utf-8 content. The browser is showing `"usu�rio"` because it tries to decode non-utf8 string as utf-8.

Comment: I've already tried with unescape function (javascript) but it does not solve it.

Comment: @MiguelE fine I'll add the function to decode it in javascript. `unescape` doesn't decode html, not sure where you got that idea .